# NextJS Deployment Error : The repository couldn't be found in your linked GitHub account

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel

I am unable to deploy my React NextJS app of vercel.
It gives the below error while clicking the deploy button :

> The repository "NetflixCloneReact" couldn't be found in your linked GitHub account.

While my repo is public:
https://github.com/karankumarshreds/NetflixCloneReact

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error.

Go to GitHub -> Settings -> Applications -> "Configure" button near Vercel -> Repository access. Either check "All repositories" or "Only select repositories" and choose your current repo for Vercel to access.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound strange but this seems to be happening only on windows machine.
This is because of a weird way how the powershell works.

---

It considers "Directory_name" === "directory_name".

---

So when I changed my directory to the project folder, it was named as "reactApp19", but while typing the folder name, I wrote *reactapp19*. Which powershell ignored and i opened VSCode further from command line and ran the next server.

*This must have resulted in mismatch in the project's name and the directories name*.
I don't know why though, after reading alot of threads:

- I did cd reactApp19 (with proper casing this time)
- Ran the next server again

*And it fixed the issue!*

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to changing permissions for some developers!

I am quoting this from Vercel website:

> Lost Git Repository Access
>
> In order for Vercel to be able to deploy commits to your Git
> repository, a Project on Vercel has to be connected to it.
>
> This connection is interrupted if the Git repository is deleted,
> archived, or if the Vercel App was uninstalled from the corresponding
> Git account or Git organization. Make sure none of these things apply.
>
> Additionally, when using GitHub, the connection is also interrupted if
> you or a member of your team modifies the access permissions of the
> Vercel GitHub App installed on the respective personal GitHub account
> or GitHub organization.
>
> To verify the access permissions of the Vercel GitHub App installed on
> your personal GitHub account, navigate to the "Applications" page and
> select "Vercel" under "Installed GitHub Apps". You will see a list of
> Git repositories that the GitHub App has access to. Make sure that the
> Git repository you're looking to connect to a Vercel Project is listed
> there.
>
> To verify the access permissions of the Vercel GitHub App installed on
> your GitHub organization, select "Vercel" under "Installed GitHub
> Apps" in the organization settings. You will see a list of Git
> repositories that the GitHub App has access to. Make sure that the Git
> repository you're looking to connect to a Vercel Project is listed
> there.

Reference: https://vercel.com/docs/platform/frequently-asked-questions#lost-git-repository-access

Answer (score 0):

[image: ERROR]

In order to fix this issue. There are a number of things that I did.

1. Download the vercel app on github (https://github.com/apps/vercel).
2. Go into your github settings and navigate to the "Applications" page and select "Vercel" under "Installed GitHub Apps". You will see a list of Git repositories that the GitHub App has access to. Make sure that the Git repository you're looking to connect to a Vercel Project is listed there.
3. Go to https://vercel.com/ and sign up (using your github account)
4. re-run the vercel command in your project folder and it should work.

[image: Success!]